# Why is a named function inside an "Immediately Invoked Function Expression" undefined when invoked from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I had this code:

Javascript

```
(function() {
    function read() {...}    
})();
```

HTML

```
<body onload="read()">
```

Console said, `read is undefined`.
After deleting the IIFE it worked, why?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Google "javascript scope" before you try to use patterns like IIFE.

Comment: Why downvote a perfectly good question?

Comment: That's the very purpose of an IIFE, encapsulation.

Comment: @DanAbramov How would you search about IIFE and not see it's about scope and encapsulation ?

Comment: @dystroy: It took me several months to fully grok JavaScript scope / closures. The problem usually is that you *think* you understand them (as a beginner JS programmer coming from languages like C#) but in fact you don't, and you find it out slowly, mistake by mistake, until you fully realize your incompetence and go about fixing it.

Comment: @dystroy How could I sanely know to google "javascript scope" if I seemingly don't know about it? [/Protest note] How would you explain that to a six year old (see comment at JaredPar's answer)?

Comment: @dollarVar Well, you knew the IIFE word. So you could have tried to learn what an IIFE was...

Comment: @dystroy Ok, I used that inline code only there once and never will again. ;) Are you reading the explanation to my only question (why?) down @JaredPar's?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this (IIFE) construct in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-iife-construct-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [long but satisfying explanation about JavaScript scope and closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md).

Since you declare `read` inside a function, it is local to that function.
Anything you declare inside a function will be local to it.

You can explicitly put it into global scope by assigning it as a property to `window`:

```
(function() {
    function read() {...}    

    window.read = read;
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing

```
(function() {
    function read() { ... }
})();
```

Is very nearly the same thing as writing

```
(function() {
    var read = function() { ... } //this is different, but not significantly so
                                  //for purposes of teaching this point
})();
```

and I think you should already understand why a `var` declared inside a function is not available outside of that function's scope.

The behavior of a function definition (`function read() { ... }`) is slightly different from the behavior of assigning a function expression to a variable (`var read = function() { ... };`) in terms of when the name of the function and the function become associated, but the two are otherwise identical.

Answer (score 1):

Because it isn't defined globally. It's only been defined *within* the scope of that immediately invoked function. To make it global either use this:

```
function read() {...}    

(function() {
    ...
})();
```

Or this:

```
(function() {
    window.read = function() {...}    
})();
```

Or better yet, just bind the `onload` event within the immediately invoked function:

```
(function() {
    function read() {...}
    window.onload = read;
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the definition of `read` is inside the IIFE.  This limits the scope of the function to the IIFE and any child functions inside of it.  The handler for `onload` is executed in the global scope and hence doesn't have access to `read`

Comment: Hey, I just came here to delete that question, but stumbled upon "voted for close because off-topic"...eah, ok? However I still need to manage creating an inner image of how javascript from an external `.js` is parsed...can I imagine it is written in the `HTML` like if it would be in `<script></script>` (without `src`, plainly)? Thanks, wahy, I chose you because you have the most rep. (Y)