# Input type=file onchange event won't fire when calling a user-defined function

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to make onchange fire for an input type of file. If I directly call an alert (like onchange="alert('a')"), it fires but if I call a user-defined function with only an alert inside, it doesn't. see below:

the html:

```
<input type='file' value='C:\fakepath' onchange="previewFile()"/>
```

the script:

```
function previewFile() {
    alert("a");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vDQxj/276/

Comment: :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950417/why-is-a-named-function-inside-an-immediately-invoked-function-expression-unde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that's not working is kind of an artifact of using JSFiddle. In the left panel, you specified to execute the JavaScript `onLoad`. You need to use the option `No wrap - in < head >` which is normally where you would place JS in a real HTML file. Change that option / check out this version of your fiddle with the option changed.

http://jsfiddle.net/pxsjjgx5/

Comment: Ok, I tried it using No wrap - in <body> and it works in jsfiddle. This would mean that the js is in the body of the html, right? Funny though, I asked this because my original script was not working even though it is in a script tag inside a ContentPlaceHolder in the bottom part of the body...

Comment: Ok, I've removed runat="server" in the input type file and now it is suddenly working. Any ideas on why might that be?

Comment: It looks like what's happening is the id of the input element is changed with runat=server. Any ideas on what can I do with this aside from removing runat=server?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer for your question. Use jQuery for this and write your code in place of alert in my code.
`$("input[type=file]").bind("change", function() {
     alert();
});`

Comment: Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/SPViradiya/qx7zq/1/  . If you do not want on click, remove the click word or use the above code.